# Limit regex matching to matched tag

Tags: regex

For the below text, need a regex that matches later

tag that contains text "pass". I tried `<p>(.*)?pass.*<\/p>` , but it matches both p tags

some random text

some random text pass some random text

Link https://regexr.com/3v59n

Thanks

Comment: can you give your desired output???

Comment: Can you include the text in your post?

Comment: You may use `<p>([^<]*)pass[^<]*<\/p>` but it is much safer to parse the string as HTML first, grab the p tag texts and the find all those containing `pass`. No regex required and works in all edge cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about `<p>[^<]*?pass.*?<\/p>`?

This way anything batween the tag and *pass* cannot be an other tag.

https://regexr.com/3v59q